# How to get data from thread to another class

Tags: java, android

Help to get the data (tdate) from the thread `t` in `main activity`...

```
    btn_in = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_insert);
    btn_in.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registerUser();
        }
    });

    Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            TextView tdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
                            long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy\nhh-mm-ss a");
                            String dateString = sdf.format(date);
                            tdate.setText(dateString);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
}
```

to the class registerUser...(tdate)

I am new to android and java...

anyone help me to learn.

```
private void registerUser() {
    String datetime = tdate.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    register(datetime);
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information about what exactly are you trying to do.

Comment: I personally prefer writing my own type of `EventListener` or you could take a look at [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) plus [`ExecturoService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

Comment: i cannot get the value tdate from the thread to the class registerUser

Comment: Declare `TextView tdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);` outside the thread.
The tdate has scope only inside the thread

Comment: ok thanks... but here i am getting date and time from the thread... i want the output in the tdate....

Comment: declare a static variable and populate the value whatever you want from the thread and access it.

Answer (score 1):

If your thread is in an other Java Class, you can create a new Interface like :

```
public interface OnTimeReceived {
    void onTimeReceived(String time);
}
```

on your MainActivity , add implements to this listener, implements the method and then set the text to your textView in the callback.

Then on the thread just call "mListener.onTimeReceived(dateString)" to update your view.

ex :

```
public class MainActivity implements OnTimeReceived {
    ...

    @Override
    public void onTimeReceived(String date) {
        mTextView.setText(date);
    }

    ...
}
```

When you create your thread class, give the listener from your activity in constructor.

Comment: As aditya says, declare your textView on the top of your activity like 

    `public class MaiActivity ... 
        TextView tdate;`

in the onCreate method do the findView : 

    `tdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);`

and on your thread you can now call 

   `tdate.setText(dateString);`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, just call the function itself with the proper arguments:

```
public void run() {
    tdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
    date = System.currentTimeMillis();
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy\nhh-mm-ss a");
    dateString = sdf.format(date);
    tdate.setText(dateString);
    registerUser(datetime); // <- Why can't you just do this?
}
```

And registerUser() should be like this:

```
private void registerUser(String datetime) {
    register(datetime);
}
```

Another option would be to make a class that receives data and has a reference to the main activity. When you finish the thread, call a function within it, and its job would be to simply call a function on the Main Activity. It's a "receiver" class, so to speak.

Also, you should avoid using sleep(1000).
Use this instead:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do something after 1000 ms
    }
}, 1000); // specify the waiting time here
```

It's much cleaner.
Let me know how it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

to complete with other answers you can try :

```
TextView tdate;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tdate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.date);
    btn_in = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_insert);
    btn_in.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registerUser();
        }
    });
    createThread();
}

private void createThread(){
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            run();
        }
    },1000);
}

private void run(){
    long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy\nhh-mm-ss a");
    String dateString = sdf.format(date);
    tdate.setText(dateString);
}
```